# Installing ixgbevf on ubuntu 14.04 EC2 instance for enhanced networking

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-14.04, virtual-network

I tried to install ixgbevf on Ubuntu 14.04 EC2 instance using the procedure described at:  [Enabling Enhanced Networking on Ubuntu](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/enhanced-networking.html#enhanced-networking-ubuntu) . I used the same version ixgbevf-2.14.2.

I got compilation errors related to PKT_HASH_TYPE_. I then followed the procedure mentioned at:  [fix PKT_HASH error](http://sourceforge.net/p/e1000/bugs/415/) .
Then  I got the below error:

```
<command-line>:0:14: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before numeric constant
include/linux/skbuff.h:740:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘skb_set_hash’
 skb_set_hash(struct sk_buff *skb, __u32 hash, enum pkt_hash_types type)
```

Has anyone faced problems with installing ixgbevf-2.14.2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried installing ixgbevf-2.16.4 instead of version 2.14.2 on Ubuntu 14.04.
This compiled without any errors. I was able to install and enable Enhanced Networking.

I think we need to inform aws to update their documentation. The document points to version 2.14.2 which has compilation issues on Ubuntu 14.04